# error C2664: 'SetDlgItemTextW' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'SYSTEMTIME' to 'LPCWSTR' 208

Tags: winapi, unicode, systemtime

I still have some trouble with understanding this with UNICODE and ANSI in win32 api..

For example, i have this code:

```
SYSTEMTIME LocalTime = { 0 };
GetSystemTime (&LocalTime);
SetDlgItemText(hWnd, 1003, LocalTime);'
```

That generates the error in the title.

Also, i should mention that it automatically adds a W after "setdlgitemtext" Some macro in VS probably.

Could someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C or C++ you can't just take an arbitrary structure and pass it to a function that expects a string. You have to convert that structure to a string first.

The Win32 functions `GetDateFormat()` and `GetTimeFormat()` can be used to convert a `SYSTEMTIME` to a string (the first one does the "date" part and the second one does the "time" part) according to the current system locale rules.

For example,

```
SYSTEMTIME LocalTime = { 0 };
GetSystemTime (&LocalTime);
wchar_t wchBuf[80];
GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_SHORTDATE, &LocalTime, NULL, wchBuf, sizeof(wchBuf) / sizeof(wchBuf[0]));
SetDlgItemText(hWnd, 1003, wchBuf);
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks! Its hard to get to know how this work. If i follow the examples from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx i still get the problem with conversion. Ive tried yours, but am unsure of how to declare _countof.

Comment: `_countof` is a vendor-specific compiler extension. If your compiler does not support `_countof`, you can use `sizeof(wchBuf)/sizeof(wchBuf[0])` instead.

Comment: I did this to resemble the msdn example:SYSTEMTIME st, lt;
    
     GetSystemTime(&st);
     GetLocalTime(&lt);

     SetDlgItemText(hWnd, 1003, st.wHour);   Seemed simple enough. But wont work.

Comment: Thanks Remy. Did that, then it tells me that "GetDateFormat" dont take 5 arguments.

Comment: I edited the example to remove the `_countof` and add the missing NULL argument (sorry about that) - you should be able to get it to compile now. `wHour` is an integer, not a string, so again you can't pass it to `SetDlgItemText` without converting it. `SetDlgItemInt`, however, can take an integer argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Did manage to get it to work now! Also with the shorter verson. when using SetDlgItemInt!